# completely disable contracts on a private network

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain

I'm running a private network I've forked from Ethereum. I'm wondering if the code is so tightly coupled I won't be able to disable contracts or if I could possibly find a line or 2 of code to take out which will break any contract attempted to be deployed on my network. Anyone know if this is possible and where I could look in the code? I've been playing with this for about a week now.

I've seen another question on here where someone suggested making the price of a contract so high that no one could afford it, while that is a good solution it doesn't suit the purposes of my experiment.

Comment: I don't know if there's a switch to turn off all contract execution, but I'd start looking at [`TransitionDb`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.8.3/core/state_transition.go#L206). It has two calls to `evm.Create` and `evm.Call`, that you want to comment out.